# Modify webpage on Share Extension iOS8

Tags: ios8, ios8-share-extension

I try to run js pre/post processor to modify webpage after finish share extension, but `finalize` method failed to run.

In Apple document it said that both Share extensions and Action extensions can benefit from this js processor, but my finalize method not get called. Only run method get called. Anyone know how to make this work ?

> Accessing a Webpage
>
> In Share extensions (on both platforms) and Action extensions (iOS
>   only), you can give users access to web content by asking Safari to
>   run a JavaScript file and return the results to the extension ...
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Here is sample project: https://app.box.com/s/9ild73l9gbmfazrmjerk

Comment: Does your real project return a non-empty array?

Comment: Yes, i tried both empty and non empty result are the same.

Comment: Hello, I have a same problem now and trying to find a way to fix. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a typo in function type, should be "finalize" instead of "finalizea".